# Problem in solving PDE

Tags: differential-equations

I have a problem in solving a type of PDE. The actual problem involves diffusion and adsorption in a trench, but here is a simpler example. I have two independent variables $t$ and $x$. There are two dependent variables $y(t,x)$ and $z(t)$. Note that $z$ is a function of $t$ only.

`NDSolve` does not accept the problem with the boundary conditions. Running this code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

pdeset = {D[y[t, x], t] == -D[y[t, x], x] + z[t], D[z[t], t] == y[t, 0]};
bc1 = {y[t, 0] == 5, y[0, x] == Cos[x]};
bc2 = {z[0] == 1};

bcAll = Flatten[{bc1, bc2}, 1];

sol = NDSolve[{pdeset, bcAll}, {y, z}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

I get the error message saying

> ```
> NDSolve::ndode: Input is not an ordinary differential equation.
> ```

I am using *Mathematica* 9.0 on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: there might be something wrong with the DE formation, you can put your equation here from book as it is (using Latex)

Comment: As pointed out by @Nasser your `z[t]` is just the integral of the boundary condition, so you can calculate that separately.

Comment: "Thanks @Nasser. I see that I have not formulated the example well. 
Wrong BC and the second equation was solvable independently. Here is a 
better example to illustrate my problem. Note that the BC is consistent, but I can't solve 2nd equation independently. I still see the problem.
"

ClearAll["Global`*"];

pdeset = {D[y[t, x], t] == -D[y[t, x], x] + z[t], 
   D[z[t], t] == y[t, 0.5]};
bc1 = {y[t, 0] == 1, y[0, x] == Cos[x]};
bc2 = {z[0] == 1};

bcAll = Flatten[{bc1, bc2}, 1];

sol = NDSolve[{pdeset, bcAll}, {y, z}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]

Answer (score 3):

The initial and boundary conditions are inconsistent.

You say `y[0, x] ==   Cos[x]` which means for any `x`. So lets try `x=0`, this gives `y[0, 0] ==   Cos[0] == 1`, but looking at `y[t, 0] == 5`, since this is valid for any `t`, then it means `y[0, 0] == 5`.

So which one is it? `y[0, 0] == 5` or `y[0, 0] == 1`

Now, if you correct this problem, and make `y[t, 0] == 1`, then it can be solved. Notice that you do not even need to include `z'[t]` in the set of equations, since its solution is there to start with. Why not solve it and just use `z[t]` directly?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
yt0 = 1;
bc1 = {y[t, 0] == yt0, y[0, x] == Cos[x]};
zt = z[t] /. First@DSolve[{z'[t] == yt0, z[0] == yt0}, z[t], t];
pdeset = D[y[t, x], t] == -D[y[t, x], x] + zt;
sol = NDSolve[{pdeset, bc1}, y, {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[y[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, 5}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]